# unable to send mails at certain time using @Scheduled

Tags: java, spring-boot, smtp, scheduling

when I am trying to send the mail using scheduler the email triggering at the time of the execution but not trggering as scheduled.
Expecting it to trigger the mail on every Friday at 6:00pm.
And in my code I am setting a cronjob in @scheduler as // @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 18 ? 1/1 FRI#3 *") and   // @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 18 ? 1/1 FRI#1 *").

```
 package com.example.Filter;h

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class FilterApplication {
    private static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dealinsights?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true", "*****",
                "******");
    }

    private static JSONObject parseMapToJSONObject(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, JSONArray>> map) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            for (String key : map.keySet()) {
                HashMap<String, JSONArray> innerMap = map.get(key);
                JSONObject innerJSON = new JSONObject();
                for (String innerKey : innerMap.keySet()) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = innerMap.get(innerKey);
                    innerJSON.put(innerKey, jsonArray);
                }
                jsonObject.put(key, innerJSON);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }

    private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, JSONArray>> parseResultSetToMap(ResultSet result, String[] parse) {
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, JSONArray>> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, JSONArray>>();
        try {
            while (result.next()) {
                String bu = result.getString("bu") != null ? result.getString("bu") : "";
                String bidManager = result.getString("bid_manager") != null ? result.getString("bid_manager") : "";
                String report = result.getString("report") != null ? result.getString("report") : "";
                String total = result.getString("total") != null ? result.getString("total") : "";
                String bidManagerMail = result.getString("bid_manager_mail") != null
                        ? result.getString("bid_manager_mail") : "";
                HashMap<String, JSONArray> innerMap = map.get(bu) != null ? map.get(bu)
                        : new HashMap<String, JSONArray>();
                HashMap<String, JSONArray> Map = map.get(bidManagerMail) != null ? map.get(bidManagerMail)
                        : new HashMap<String, JSONArray>();
                JSONArray jsonArray = innerMap.get(bidManager) != null ? innerMap.get(bidManager) : new JSONArray();
                JSONArray jsonArrayMail = innerMap.get(bidManagerMail) != null ? innerMap.get(bidManagerMail)
                        : new JSONArray();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("report", report);
                jsonObject.put("total", total);
                jsonObject.put("bid_manager_mail", bidManagerMail);
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                innerMap.put(bidManager, jsonArray);
                map.put(bu, innerMap);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

    // @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 18 ? 1/1 FRI#1 *")
    // @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 18 ? 1/1 FRI#3 *")
    // @Scheduled(cron = "0 45 10 ? 1/1 FRI#4 *")
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * ?")
    private static void sendEmail(Session session, String fromAddress, String[] toAddress, String[] ccAddress,
            String[] bccAddress, String subject, String body) throws AddressException, MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
        for (String to : toAddress)
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        for (String cc : ccAddress)
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress(cc));
        for (String bcc : bccAddress)
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(body, "text/html");
        Transport.send(message);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
        System.out.println("schedule tasks using cron jobs - " + now);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AddressException, MessagingException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String host = "*******";
        String port = "25";
        final String user = "*******";
        final String password = "******";

        String to = "******";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
            }
        });

        String msg = "yes";

        String report = "";
        String total1 = null;

        // try {
        // String technologyText = " ";
        // String commsmediaText = " ";
        // String totalDynamicKey = null;
        // String myDriver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        // Class.forName(myDriver);
        // Connection connection = getConnection();
        // CallableStatement callableStatement = connection
        // .prepareCall("{call get_pursuit_quality_report_filter_data()}");
        // ResultSet result = callableStatement.executeQuery();
        // String[] parse = { "report", "bu", "bid_manager", "total",
        // "bid_manager_mail" };
        // HashMap<String, HashMap<String, JSONArray>> map =
        // parseResultSetToMap(result, parse);
        // JSONObject jsonObject = parseMapToJSONObject(map);
        // JSONObject Technology = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Technology");
        // JSONObject commsmedia = jsonObject.getJSONObject("CommsMedia");
        // Iterator keys = Technology.keys();
        // while (keys.hasNext()) {
        // totalDynamicKey = (String) keys.next();
        // // System.out.println("keys:" + totalDynamicKey);
        // JSONArray totalDynamicValue =
        // Technology.getJSONArray(totalDynamicKey);
        // JSONObject objMail = totalDynamicValue.getJSONObject(0);
        // String bidMail = objMail.optString("bid_manager_mail");
        // technologyText += "This is " + totalDynamicKey
        // + "'s Report for any furthur queries please reach out to " + bidMail
        // + "<br/>";
        // technologyText += "<table width='100%' border='1' align='center'>" +
        // "<tralign='center'>"
        // + "<td><b> Report <b></td>" + "<td><b> Total <b></td>" + "</tr>";
        //
        // for (int j = 0; j < totalDynamicValue.length(); j++) {
        // JSONObject obj = totalDynamicValue.getJSONObject(j);
        // total1 = obj.getString("total");
        // report = obj.getString("report");
        //
        // technologyText += "<tralign='center'>" + "<td>" + report + "</td>" +
        // "<td>" + total1 + "</td>"
        // + "</tr>";
        // }
        // technologyText += "</table>" + "<br/>" + "<br/>";
        // }
        // technologyText += "Thank You" + "<br/>" + "DealInsights Portal Tool
        // Team.";
        // Iterator keyss = commsmedia.keys();
        // while (keyss.hasNext()) {
        // totalDynamicKey = (String) keyss.next();
        // JSONArray totalDynamicValue =
        // commsmedia.getJSONArray(totalDynamicKey);
        // JSONObject objMail = totalDynamicValue.getJSONObject(0);
        // String bidMail = objMail.optString("bid_manager_mail");
        // commsmediaText += "This is " + totalDynamicKey
        // + "'s Report for any furthur queries please reach out to " + bidMail
        // + "<br/>";
        // commsmediaText += "<table width='100%' border='1' align='center'>" +
        // "<tralign='center'>"
        // + "<td><b> Report <b></td>" + "<td><b> Total <b></td>" + "</tr>";
        //
        // for (int i = 0; i < totalDynamicValue.length(); i++) {
        // JSONObject obj = totalDynamicValue.getJSONObject(i);
        // total1 = obj.getString("total");
        // report = obj.getString("report");
        //
        // commsmediaText += "<tralign='center'>" + "<td>" + report + "</td>" +
        // "<td>" + total1 + "</td>"
        // + "</tr>";
        // }
        // commsmediaText += "</table>" + "<br/>" + "<br/>";
        // }
        // commsmediaText += "Thank You" + "<br/>" + "DealInsights Portal Tool
        // Team.";
        // String[] toAddress = { "******" };
        // String[] ccAddress = { "****" };
        // String[] bccAddress = {};
        // sendEmail(session, user, toAddress, ccAddress, bccAddress, "Data
        // quality reports for Technology",
        // technologyText);
        // System.out.println(" Technology message sent successfully...");
        //
        // String[] tocommsAddress = { "******" };
        // String[] cccommsAddress = { "****",
        // ****" };
        // String[] bcccoAddress = {};
        // sendEmail(session, user, tocommsAddress, cccommsAddress,
        // bcccoAddress,
        // "Data quality reports for CommsMedia", commsmediaText);
        // System.out.println(" Commsmedia message sent successfully...");
        //
        // }
        //
        // catch (SQLException e) {
        // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }

        try {

            String body = "HI";
            String[] toAddress = { ****** };
            String[] ccAddress = { ******};
            String[] bccAddress = {};
            sendEmail(session, user, ccAddress, ccAddress, bccAddress, "Scheduler Testing", body);
            System.out.println("Mail successfully sent");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your HOST has to be smtp.office365.com. Additionally you have to ensure that in a minimum TLSv1.2 is used.

```
    final Properties config = new Properties();
    config.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    config.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    config.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
    config.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
    config.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    config.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
```

Microsoft has this written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#how-to-set-up-smtp-auth-client-submission).